# How to download data from an ASP.Net webpage to an Excel file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I need to download the data in a table and also a picture to an excel spreadsheet. I am currently able to create the excel spreadsheet on the website, but how do I get the data into the spreadsheet?

```
protected void btn_ExcelDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("");
    path = path + @"\Resources\MessageStatus.xlsx";
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: you have to export the content to the excel sheet. if you are using grid, you shud be able to do that easily otherwise you have to write your own export logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done this using this class

```
void WriteToXls(string fromfilePath, string targetFileName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromfilePath)) 
        {
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = "utf-8";
            response.ContentType = "text/xls";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", targetFileName));
            response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(fromfilePath));
            response.End();
        }
    }
```